# Stripe - How do you send decimal amounts to the API for a Payment?

Tags: php, stripe-payments, e-commerce

I'm migrating an e-commerce platform from using SagePay to Stripe.

The docs show using an `amount` figure of `1099` and a currency of `gbp` (https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#web-create-payment-intent).

As far as I can tell this means £10.99 (not £1099). *But this is extremely unclear in their docs - I am assuming this is the case.*

If I try and send `amount => 10.99` through their API, I get an error message in the response:

```
  "error": {
    "code": "parameter_invalid_integer",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-invalid-integer",
    "message": "Invalid integer: 10.99",
    "param": "amount",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
```

With SagePay you would actually send `10.99` as the amount.

So, with Stripe, do you have to convert all amounts to the single base unit of a currency (pence in the case of GBP), for example if the amount was £10.99 you'd do `(10.99 * 100)` then send `1099`?

The docs don't actually make this clear. If you read up on Decimal Amounts (https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/decimal-amounts) in their docs it says you can use a parameter called `amount_decimal` but this will also give an error if sent through their API:

```
$intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
    'amount_decimal' => 10.99,
    'currency' => 'gbp',
    // Verify your integration in this guide by including this parameter
    'metadata' => ['integration_check' => 'accept_a_payment'],
]);
```

Results in an error saying the parameter, `amount_decimal`, is unknown (even though it's in their docs?):

```
"error": {
    "code": "parameter_unknown",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-unknown",
    "message": "Received unknown parameter: amount_decimal",
    "param": "amount_decimal",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
```

My assumption is that this error is because this part of the documentation is referring to billing for "plans" as opposed to one-off Payments. I'm wanting to accept a card payment for one-off invoices so have used the [Accept a Card Payment](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment) docs.

So my question is: Do you just send the amount in the smallest unit of the currency (e.g. `10.99 * 100` for £10.99), or is there some other method where it can be passed as a decimal (i.e. `10.99`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/currencies#zero-decimal):

> All API requests expect amounts to be provided in a currency’s smallest unit. For example, to charge 10 USD, provide an amount value of 1000 (i.e., 1000 cents). For zero-decimal currencies, still provide amounts as an integer but without multiplying by 100. For example, to charge ¥500, provide an amount value of 500.

You will never pass a decimal point for `amount` anywhere in the Stripe API. Most API endpoints do not support `amount_decimal` unless it's explicitly listed in the [API reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api).

Answer (score -1):

convert your currency to cent i did in php
$doller=42.20;
bcmul($doller, 100);