# Type conversion error in c# when converting Decimal values in Long

Tags: c#

I am using STRIPE API and when I pass a value of anything in amount except decimals it works good for ex if I provide **20** as **paymentDto.Amount** to this code

```
  PaymentIntentCreateOptions options = new PaymentIntentCreateOptions
                {
                    Amount = Convert.ToInt64(paymentDto.Amount) * 100,
                    Currency = "usd",
                    Customer = customerStripeId
                };
```

It works fine but when I try to give **20.25** then It gives me error **"Input string was not in a correct format."**

Note:
I am multiplying by 100 because it is the requirement of STRIPE API, and the data type of Amount in its api is **long**

Please help.

Comment: Decimal values are not integer values. What do you think should happen when you convert `20.25` into a type that **cannot** represent the `.25` component?

Comment: Did you consider that 20.25 is not an `int64`?

Comment: What is the type of `paymentDto.Amount`?

Comment: Do you just want to *magic* the decimal places away?

Comment: for now I have set paymentDto.Amount type to string, as this would be sent by android device to my API

Comment: maybe you want `decimal.TryParse(paymentDto.Amount, out var bob) ? bob: throw something`

Comment: If I won't accept decimal places in my API then how would it work? as if the amount in front-end is lets say 20 Dollars & 10 Cents then my API would IGNORE 10 Cents and take 20 Dollars, 

I have found a thread on stackoverflow too.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61230916/stripe-how-do-you-send-decimal-amounts-to-the-api-for-a-payment

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/currencies#minimum-and-maximum-charge-amounts

Comment: You might want to do math.floor or math.ceiling to get the nearest whole number which then you can convert to long.

Comment: Guessing that `paymentDto.Amount` is a string, not a decimal. `Convert.ToInt64(20.25M)` works just fine and returns 20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the reason:

> amount REQUIRED Amount intended to be collected by this PaymentIntent.
> A positive integer representing how much to charge in the smallest
> currency unit (e.g., 100 cents to charge $1.00 or 100 to charge ¥100,
> a zero-decimal currency). The minimum amount is $0.50 US or equivalent
> in charge currency. The amount value supports up to eight digits
> (e.g., a value of 99999999 for a USD charge of $999,999.99).

You can find it in their docs:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create

---

So the solution is to change your usd amount to cents

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cents = ConvertDollarsToCents(100.10m);
        Console.WriteLine(cents);
    }

    public static int ConvertDollarsToCents(decimal dollars)
    {
        return (int)(dollars * 100);
    }
}
```

Input:

> 100.10

Output:

> 10010